# Jquery bind events triggering twice in Chrome but works in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Jquery event is triggered twice in Chrome but triggers only once in IE. The click event is bind to few tags so when the user click on the tag then the target event is triggered twice in Chrome latest version (75) and eventually ajax calls are called twice on target.

I have tried with bind/ unbind methods, it did not work.

```
      $("#idElement a img").unbind("click").bind("click", function (event) 
      {
            var target = event.currentTarget;
            if (!dataSaved()) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            } else {
                $("#idElement a img").unbind("click")
                $(target).click();
            }
        });




         $("#idElement a img").on("click", function (event) {
            var target = event.currentTarget;
            if (!dataSaved()) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            } else {
                $("#idElement a img").off("click")
                $(target).click();
            }
        });
```

When the target event is clicked, call exactly only once to avoid issues with duplicate ajax calls.

Comment: Sounds like an X/Y problem
1. Use `.on` instead of `.bind` 2. You likely have an async issue when calling `!dataSaved()` I am almost certain it is trying to return the state of an async call. Post more code. But do think about rewriting from scratch. It sounds like you have a mess on your hands. What exactly are you trying to do when you click the img, click on something else?

Comment: I have to go with stopImmediatePropagation() to avoid issue with .on function. Along with manage events manually and change the list order as events are fired as per the order in the Event list.

Answer (score 0):

.on enough for you dont use .bind

```
 $(".wrapper").on("click","#idElement a img", function (event) {
    var target = event.currentTarget;
    if (!dataSaved()) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        $("#idElement a img").off("click")
        $(target).click();
    }
});
```

.wrapper is your control area, container or body etc.